# Returning an number from file which can be found after a specific pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have been stuck at a question where i read from a file, line by line and store those lines as a string inside an arrayList. That list is then cycled through to find an int which comes after "rings=" the pattern i use is "(?<=rings=)[0-9]{1}" I have a print statement in the following code to show me this int but it is never used meaning the method probably does not find that int. An example of where it gets the int from is.

```
//Event=ThermostatDay,time=12000
//Event=Bell,time=9000,rings=5
//Event=WaterOn,time=6000
```

The code is

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileToArray.size(); i++) {

    try {
        String friskForX = fileToArray.get(i).toString();
        Matcher xTimeSeeker = rinngerPat.matcher(friskForX);
        if (xTimeSeeker.group() != null) {
            System.out.println("will ring more then once ");
            xTimesRing = xTimeSeeker.group();
            int xTimeSeekerInt = Integer.parseInt(xTimesRing);
            System.out.println(xTimeSeekerInt);
        }
    }
    //this catches it but does nothing since some files might not have x value.
    catch (IllegalStateException e) { } 
}
```

Comment: Why not skip regex entirely and just parse each line by commas?

Comment: I dont think i follow.
These events are instructions i will be reading off a file, which i cant change.

Comment: Each line is comma delimited right? Split each line by commas. Check each index, see if it begins with `rings=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your pattern to: `.*rings=(\\d+).*`

```
String pattern=".*rings=(\\d+).*";
Pattern rinngerPat = Pattern.compile(pattern);
```

Then `group(1)` will have your digit

```
for(String line : fileToArray) {
    Matcher xTimeSeeker = rinngerPat.matcher(line);
    if(xTimeSeeker.find()) {
       xTimesRing = xTimeSeeker.group(1);
       int xTimeSeekerInt = Integer.parseInt(xTimesRing);
       System.out.println(xTimeSeekerInt);
    }
}
```

Self contained example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> fileToArray = new ArrayList<>();
    fileToArray.add("Event=ThermostatDay,time=12000");
    fileToArray.add("Event=Bell,time=9000,rings=5");
    fileToArray.add("Event=WaterOn,time=6000");
    String pattern=".*rings=(\\d+).*";
    Pattern rinngerPat = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    String xTimesRing;
    for(String line : fileToArray) {
        Matcher xTimeSeeker = rinngerPat.matcher(line);
        if(xTimeSeeker.find()) {
            xTimesRing = xTimeSeeker.group(1);
            int xTimeSeekerInt = Integer.parseInt(xTimesRing);
            System.out.println(xTimeSeekerInt);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort .
I first used your pattern , it did not return anything in my code. then when i used your for loop , it gave me an error telling me that fileToArray is an object so String line can not be used

Comment: Seems that your for loop was not working for me due to the way i had defined my list. 
It worked once i redefined it.
Thank you again for your time and effort it works now